# Why constants are not allowed in c# interface?

Tags: c#

```
interface IA
{
   public const int months = 12;
}

public class A : IA
{
}
```

Why constants are not allowed in interface?

Comment: A field is an implementation detail, an interface is a contract that aims to abstract implementation away.

Comment: In general one should avoid public fields in favour of public properties with private fields. (except in high performance scenarios) So we'd write your interface as `int X{get;set;}`

Comment: @CodeInChaos, you completely miss the point of properties versus fields. int X { get; set; } is just noise compared with int x. If you aren't making the setter at least internal, if not private, then use a field as it's effectively the same thing.

Comment: @DavidArno: Not quite, as a field will mean a change of the public interface, if in any future version the getter and/or the setter has to do anything special, and thus a property is required then.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper, that just makes me shudder. Having a completely mutable property int X{get;set;} is bad enough, but the idea that might change in the future such that either get or set has side-effects is just plain horrible. If it has to be completely mutable, then I'd be happier having it as a field as I know what it's doing then.

Comment: @DavidArno: Who says anything about side-effects? The change might be as little as checking an assigned value, as is the case in many classes from the base class library. Using a field would break encapsulation - not just in the current version, but in any (binary compatible) future versions of the class.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the indicated question; this question is specifically about *constants*.  It would be a perfectly reasonable feature to allow constant fields in an interface, eg: `interface I { int Search(); const int NotFound = -1; }` and now it is clear that an implementation should return -1 if the search fails. The reason this feature does not exist is the same reason every other sensible feature does not exist: no one ever implemented it. The design team does not need a reason to NOT implement features.